# Inserting data into different sheets in Google Sheet

Tags: java, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I try create in google sheet form to inserting data into several sheets at once.
When you open the form you have field for entering some values and Checkbox where you can select a sheet to enter data.
I have a question, how can I make data to be written to several sheets at once?
Below my code.

[image]

```html
 <b>test 1.1</b><br />
   
<br>
    <form>
   <br>
  Nr item:<br>
    <input id="NrItem" name="NrItem" type="text" />
 <br>

<br>
<input  name="choices" type="checkbox" value="something1" /> sheet1
<br>
<br>
<input  name="choices" type="checkbox" value="something2" /> sheet2
<br>
<br>
<input name="choices" type="checkbox" value="something3" /> sheet3
<br>

  <br>
<br>
   <input onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Add Row" />
   
   <input onclick="google.script.host.close()" type="button" value="Exit" />
   </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function formSubmit() {
            google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
            
        }
    </script>
```

```js
function demoHtmlServices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setWidth(200).setHeight(550);
  ss.show(html);
}

//getValuesFromForm
function getValuesFromForm(form){
  var NrItem = form.NrItem,
      date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([date, NrItem]);
    
  
  }
```

Comment: I updated my answer as Edit. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following modification?

In order to retrieve values from `input`, it uses `this.parentNode` for `formSubmit()`. By this, at `getValuesFromForm(form)`, `NrItem` can be retrieved by `form.NrItem`.

#### Modified script :

This is the modification for the HTML file.

```
.
.
.
  <input onclick="formSubmit(this.parentNode)" type="button" value="Add Row" />
  <input onclick="google.script.host.close()" type="button" value="Exit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function formSubmit(e) {
    google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(e);
  }
</script>
```

#### Note :

When `sampletext` was inputted to the text box and the checkboxes of sheet1 and sheet2 are checked, `this.parentNode` becomes

```
{"NrItem":"sampletext","choices":["something1","something2"]}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

---

### Edit

If the sheet names of Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 are constant, you can use following sample.

#### Modified HTML :

```
<br>
<input  name="choices" type="checkbox" value="Sheet1" /> sheet1
<br>
<br>
<input  name="choices" type="checkbox" value="Sheet2" /> sheet2
<br>
<br>
<input name="choices" type="checkbox" value="Sheet3" /> sheet3
<br>
```

#### Modified GAS :

```
var NrItem = form.NrItem,
    date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i in sheets) {
  for (var j in form.choices) {
    if (form.choices[j] == sheets[i].getName()) {
      sheets[i].appendRow([date, NrItem]);
    }
  }
}
```

If this was not the sample you want, feel free to tell me.

Comment: @J.Doe Welcome. Thank you, too.

Comment: Hi, I have one question to this script, i work when I want put information in more than one sheet, but what if I want put information only in one sheet, for example in "sheet 3".

Comment: @J.Doe Can you submit it with the detail information as a new question?